# Uninstall app icon from home screen when app is uninstall

Tags: android

I have put `app_icon` on Home Screen when app is install

now want to remove it, when app is going to uninstall

i know how to remove `app_icon` but dont know on which event i need to do this

Can any one provides me solution for this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Shouldn't the icon be deleted automatically on app uninstall?

Answer (score 0):

When you uninstall an app the app shortcut icon will be removed (however many copies you've made).

Answer (score 0):

There is no `event` to track the uninstallation of an application. Also, as Warpzit said, the icons are automatically removed anyway.